# iOS - How to open the links in the default browser (Safari or Chrome) instead of the in-app browser?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

- I am using the QR Reader App to scan the QR Code with the link inside(for example: http://example.com)
- Then example.com will be open in QR Reader in-app browser (I don't know what is it).
- In my website, I want to have a button called "Open In Default Browser" (Safari or Chrome), and touch this button to launch example.com in my default browser on phone (not in-app browser).
- Any suggestion? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *apikey = @"your url";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:apikey];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Is objective C still an acceptable response to iOS questions?

Comment: There's no swift or objective-c language tag. So why not?

Comment: Sorry guys. I means not Objective C or Swift. I am asking the way to detect in webapp. Any Javascript or HTML5 script?